# Conditional Variance with projection

Tags: probability

I have this seemingly easy problem about conditional variance but I failed to solve it.

Suppose we have 
$$p_0 + \lambda y = E[v|p_0 + \beta v + u = y]$$

where 
$$\beta = \frac{1}{2\lambda} = \frac{\sigma_u}{\sqrt{\Sigma_0}}$$

and $v \sim N(p_0, \Sigma_0)$, $u \sim N(0,\sigma_u^2)$. $\textbf{What is $\text{Var}[v|y]$ then?}$

I'm reading a paper and I know the conclusion is that $\text{Var}[v|y]=\frac{1}{2}\text{Var}[v]$. But I don't know how to show it. (He said using  simple calculation) I tried to calculate $\text{Var}[v|y]$ by $\text{Var}[v|y] = E[v^2 | y ] - E[v|y]^2$ but I don't know the functional form of $E[v^2 | y ]$. I also tried to express $v$ in terms of $y$ as 
$$v = \frac{1}{\beta}\big(y- p_0 - u \big)$$ and calculate the variance 
$$\text{Var}(v) = \frac{1}{\beta^2} \big(\text{Var}(y) + \sigma_u^2 \big)=\frac{1}{\beta^2}\text{Var}(y) + \Sigma_0$$

but these are unconditional variances, I don't know how to relate them to conditional ones.

Comment: "am I going the wrong direction?" Which direction is this?

Comment: Hm. I tried to calculate var[v|y] by $E[v^2|y] - E[v|y]^2$

Comment: Sorry but this is hardly a "direction".

Comment: Ok..So I used the wrong description..Can you kindly help me out?

Comment: Sure--as soon as you show some personal input.

Comment: Fair enough. Please allow me some time.

Comment: @Did I have written all I have done...

Comment: The result follows from simple computations of conditional distributions in gaussian families. Assume without loss of generality that $p_0=0$ (or replace $v$ by $v-p_0$ in the following), then the exercise can be rewritten (somewhat more rigorously) as follows: *Let $(U,V)$ be some gaussian vector with $U\sim N(0,u^2)$ and $V\sim N(0,v^2)$, consider $Y=U+bV$ with $b=u/v$ and assume that $E(V\mid Y)=Y/(2b)$. Show that $\text{var}(V\mid Y)=\tfrac12v^2$.* // To prove this, one can first choose $a$ such that $X=aU-V$ is independent of $Y$. Then $V=(aY-X)/(ab+1)$ hence $E(V\mid Y)=aY/(ab+1)$ ...

Comment: ... Comparing this to $E(V\mid Y)=Y/(2b)$ shows that $ab=1$ and that $U$ and $V$ are independent. Furthermore, $\text{var}(V\mid Y)=(ab+1)^{-2}\text{var}(X)=\tfrac14\text{var}(X)$. By definition of $X$, $\text{var}(X)=a^2u^2+v^2=2v^2$ hence we are done.

Comment: Oh....Yes, I forgot to use Gaussian Family...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were reading Kyle (85) and your question is about the static case. In that model, the author assumes joint normality for asset payoff ($v$) and noise demand ($u$). Given this assumption, it follows that

$Var[V|y] = Var[v] - \frac{Cov[v,y]^2}{Var[y]} = \frac{\Sigma_0}{2}. $